# I am not sure how to route with a variable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have and edit anchor tag corresponding to my entry on my webpage.
So when I click on edit link.

I get unique id attached to my URI

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/edit/3
```

My href looks like this

```
<a href="/cars/edit/{{$car->id}}" >
```

And my corresponding web.php looks like this

```
Route::get('/cars/edit/{{ $cars->id }}/',function (Request $request, $id)
```

And I want to use that particular id to update a particular data entry in my DB.

I am not sure how to fix this

When I click on edit I get this

[image: This is how my webpage looks]

Comment: `Route::get('/cars/edit/{{ $cars->id }}...` -> `Route::get('/cars/edit/{id}...`

Comment: I did It doesn't work

Comment: Route::get('/cars/edit/{id}', function ($id) {
    return $id;
});

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a chapter on [Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: `Route::get('cars/edit/{$id}',function($id){
        $car=DB::table('cars')->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('carsops.update')->with('car',$car);
    });`
This is what I am trying to do and it shows webpage not found

Comment: Parameters in routes don't take a `$`. As @AlbertoSinigaglia already pointed out (and by reading the link I posted) it would be `Route::get('/cars/edit/{id}...`.

Comment: Oh okay thank you guys for helping I am little new could not get that detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you about Laravel routes. Route is a amazing solution in the Laravel framework. In the future, you should more about Route in the official Laravel documentaion.

How to right solve your problem?

A first, describe `edit` method in the `routes/web.php` like to bellow

```php
Route::get('/cars/edit/{id}', [CarController::class, 'edit'])->name('cars.edit');
```

A second step, describe `edit` method in the `CarController` like bellow

```php
class CarController extend Controller
{
...
    public function edit(Request $request, int $id): view
    {
        // $id - is car ID 
        // some code

        return view(...)
    }
...
}
```

Well done.